# PHP ignoring config file

Tags: php, ubuntu, magic-quotes-gpc

I'm trying to turn off magic_quotes_gpc in PHP. I'm running PHP with Apache and Ubuntu.

I have in my config file (/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini):

```
magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Where I create a page with phpinfo() it shows magic_quotes_gpc as on. I've also looked in Additional .ini files parsed and there is no setting for it.

Why is PHP ignoring this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to add/edit in php.ini

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

after adding restart your apache services for taking effect this

You can turn them off using .htaccess with:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

and also using php if writable php.ini

```
ini_set('magic_quotes_gpc' , 0 );
```

Comment: In my question I clearly state that I have that in my config file

Comment: @Richard, but it should be `magic_quotes_gpc = off`, see equal sign? So remove your minus for this guy's answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is deprecated so, don't rely on it. Mmmmmmmkay?

Secondly, Check

> Loaded Configuration File

Under `phpinfo()`

[image]

Also Add :

`php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off` to your `.htaccess` file.

Cool?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be loading the correct config file. In my config file I set it to Off but it shows as On in phpinfo()

Comment: also, restart Apache and see if changes reflect :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently make this change? If so, you have to restart PHP for it to take effect.

Comment: No, it was already off in the ini, however it is on in my scripts. I have restarted PHP